# Accessibility features in GameMaker Studio

Tags: accessibility, game-engine, game-maker

I have begun using GameMaker Studio to develop a game. From what I've gathered, it uses its own kind of scripting language. Since the capabilities of interfacing a GameMaker Studio project with outside coding, I am curious to know what one could do within GameMaker Studio, accessibility-wise, e.g. implementing an aurial interface on top of the visual, or implementing haptic feedback for a mobile game.

I have searched for an answer to this on Google, but haven't found anything useful. The scripting help files don't provide me with anything useful, either.

The question I have, really, is whether I should invest the time to learn GameMaker Studio or if I'm better off creating my own engine (or using some other engine). The thing is: making my games accessible to e.g. people with visual impairments is crucial to my business.

Comment: If you can't find anything related to accessibility, it's probably not a feature of GM. It also depends a lot on the target platform(s), ie mobile vs web vs desktop whether you can access accessibility features of that specific platform.

Comment: To extend the above: GM is aimed at "multiplatform-development", as such they have to aim -except for really "HOT" features- for the lowest common denominator. Adding such accessibility does not fall under this - for this there exist the "extension mechanism" which allows you to execute "extensions" (dlls/dylibs/whatever the platform supports).  As for the question if GM is useful for your goal: it indeed doesn't help with this/have this feature. However I honestly doubt many game engines have this, especially if you aim for cross platform development with iOS/android/winphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using GM:S. I personally use it for my projects. The built in scripting language is called GML, and the entire language is documented [here](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/).

GML is very similar to C in syntax, and contains a lot of modern things built in. But if you really hate GML, you can still use DLLs made in other languages in GM, with 3 functions in GML. (There are ways to do haptic feedback documented in the link I provided.)

But it's your choice.